# Getting Neo4J running on OpenShift

Tags: docker, neo4j, openshift

I am trying to get the Bitnami Neo4j image running on OpenShift (testing on my local Minishift), but I am unable to connect. I am following the steps outlined in this issue (now closed), however, now I cannot access the external IP for the load balancer.

Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Deploy Image (bitnami/neo4j)
2. Create service for the load balancer,
   using the YAML supplied in the [issue](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-neo4j/issues/3) mentioned
3. Get the external IP
   address for the LB (oc get services) The command in step 3 lists 2
   of the same IP addresses, and when I attempt to go to this IP in my
   browser it times out.
4. I can create a route that points to port 7374 on the IP of the LB, but 
   then I get the same error as reported in the aforementioned issue.
   (ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security 
   constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not 
   available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development 
   console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure neo4j to accept non-local connections. E.g.:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
```

Source: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure/

Comment: Thanks! How do I do this inside a Docker container? There does not appear to be any editor installed (vim/Nano) on the container itself, so I am trying to use sed but I do not have permissions.

Comment: @user1314147 You have a few options, see https://neo4j.com/developer/docker-run-neo4j/#_overriding_default_config e.g. env variable `-e "NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_address=0.0.0.0:7687"`

Comment: I take that back, it was working initially now it is not working again. I simply added that as an environment variable for my deployment on OpenShift and then ran an oc port-forward POD 7474:7474 and attempted to login at 127.0.0.1:7474 but I get the same WebSocket error...

Comment: @3348604 I appreciate the help, however, the problem is a little more complicated than I led on: it is a completely different animal when trying to deploy on OpenShift, you do now need to set that environment variable you need to forward ports 7474 and 7687. This will allow neo to authenticate locally, however, this is not feasible in a production setting so I am reverting back to Mongo and GraphQL. I gave you the bounty anyways as your suggestion was helpful. I apologize for the misunderstanding!